# How to setup Appium(framework) for iOS Device Automation on Windows OS.?

Tags: ios, macos, automation, appium

How should I setup Appium framework to test the application on iOS Device by using the Windows OS. is that possible.?
This special case is because, I have an application(Web GUI) which runs only on Windows OS and does the transaction with iOS mobile(via USB port) using the app on the device. So, I need to run the automation framework of iOS(Appium) on Windows OS.
is this possible by Virtual Machine etc. ??

Comment: you can try out a VM and go come back with the challenges faced during that.

Answer (score 0):

As per Appium Platform Support mentioned on portal [here](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.1.0/?java#appium-on-real-ios-devices)

> A Mac with XCode and the XCode Command Line Developer Tools

is must. So as per my knowledge, that is not possible.